# Pulling data from a HTML table to store the values in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering how I can get the values out of the database into a variable in javascript. I am not a web developer and so I'm not that experienced in HTML/CSS/Javascript so any help is appreciated.
My code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#display").click(function() {

        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to display.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "GetOccupancy.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
            success: function(response) {
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
                //alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

function GetCellValues() {
    var table = document.getElementById('#responsecontainer');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do it would be to set up a two-dimensional array (matrix), and push the values in:

```
function GetCellValues() {
    var table = document.getElementById('#responsecontainer');

    var tableMatrix = []; //Set up an empty array (put it outside the function if you want to use it again somewhere else)

    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {

        var rowValues = []; //Create an array to hold all the values in this row

        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            
            rowValues.push( table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML ); //Add the values to the row
            
        }

        tableMatrix.push(rowValues); //Now add the row to the table matrix
    }
}
```

However, it really depends on how you want to be able to access it. In fact, it might be usable just the way it is - i.e. you could just copy over `table.rows` to a new variable and store it that way. It all depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: basically i need to pull the data, store it as a variable and insert them into the html so that the value can appear on the webpage

Comment: Doesn't it already show up in the `$("#responsecontainer")`?